# C++ - Linked List code - LNode was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am writing a class for a linked list in C++ and I am having an issue when writing the operator overload for <<. My class' header is:

```
class LList
{
   private:
      struct LNode
      {
         LNode ();
         int data;
         LNode * next;
      };
   public:
      LList ();
      LList (const LList & other);
      ~LList ();
      LList & operator = (const LList & other);
      bool operator == (const LList & other);
      int Size () const;
      friend ostream & operator << (ostream & outs, const LList & L);
      bool InsertFirst (const int & value);
      bool InsertLast (const int & value);
      bool DeleteFirst ();
      bool DeleteLast ();
   private:
      LNode * first;
      LNode * last;
      int size;
};
```

and the operator is:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & outs, const LList & L){ 
    LNode *np;
    np=L.first;
    while(np!=NULL){
        outs<<np->data;
        np=np->next;
    }
    return outs;
}
```

When I compile the code I get an error:

```
LList.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LList&)’:
LList.cpp:36:2: error: ‘LNode’ was not declared in this scope
  LNode *np;
  ^
LList.cpp:36:9: error: ‘np’ was not declared in this scope
  LNode *np;
```

I thought I could instantiate a struct inside a friend function but it looks like that doesn't work. Any of you know what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `operator<<` is a global function, you need to access your inner class with:

```
LList::LNode *np;
```

Since this function is a `friend` of `LList`, then it can access the private `LNode` class.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `operator<<` overload is a non-member function, you'll need to use `LList::LNode`.

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & outs, const LList & L){ 

    LList::LNode *np;
 // ^^^^^

    np=L.first;
    while(np!=NULL){
        outs<<np->data;
        np=np->next;
    }
    return outs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `LNode` isn't in global scope, it's a nested class of `LList`. You have to write:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & outs, const LList & L){ 
    LList::LNode *np = L.first;
    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    /* rest as before */
}
```