# "is private within this context" is being thrown for function which should not be private (GCC 5.3.0, C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am attempting to create a queue, which requires the creation of another object stored in the queue. The errors are

```
binary.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
binary.cpp:183:1: error: ‘Queue<T>::Queue(T) [with T = binary<std::basic_string<char> >*]’ is private
 Queue<T>::Queue(T item){
 ^
binary.cpp:286:65: error: within this context
  Queue<binary<string>*>* queue = new Queue<binary<string>*>(tree);
                                                                 ^
```

and

```
binary.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Queue<T>::Queue(T) [with T = binary<std::basic_string<char> >*]’:
binary.cpp:286:65:   required from here
binary.cpp:132:1: error: ‘Link<T>::Link(T) [with T = binary<std::basic_string<char> >*]’ is private
 Link<T>::Link(T item){
 ^
binary.cpp:184:7: error: within this context
  head = new Link<T>(item);
```

The first is the instantiation of the Queue, and the second comes from the Queue's constructor, which is called in the instantiation line in the first error. The important declarations and definitions are:

```
template<class T>
class Link{
    Link(T item);

    private:
    T content;
    Link<T>* next;
};

template<class T>
Link<T>::Link(T item){
    content = item;
    next = NULL;
}

template<class T>
class Queue{
    Queue();
    Queue(T item);

    private:
    Link<T>* head;
    Link<T>* end;
    int length;
};

template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(T item){
    head = new Link<T>(item);
    end = head;
    length = 1;
}
```

The Link class is declared and defined before the Queue class, and both are declared and defined before they are used in code. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, both `Link` and `Queue` have private constructors. A `class` defaults to `private` access for its members, either declare your constructors as `public`, or change both to `struct`.

Comment: Very close, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140626/c-linked-list-code-lnode-was-not-declared-in-this-scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default class members are private, even you use `private` access specifier later, Your code is like :

```
template<class T>
class Queue{
    Queue(); //Implicitly private
    Queue(T item); //Implicitly private

    private: //explicit private
    Link<T>* head;
    Link<T>* end;
    int length;
};
```

so you need to make constructors public  :

```
template<class T>
class Queue{
    public:
    Queue(); 
    Queue(T item);
    private:
    Link<T>* head;
    Link<T>* end;
    int length;
};
```

Same goes for `Link<T>` class template.

Comment: It's always the smallest syntax errors that I miss. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ceaston7 Well look at the compiler error (mind the private word) : `error: ‘Queue<T>::Queue(T) [...]’ is **private**`